# Texture not visible when redered in flutter, but for same model texture is visible in windows 3D viewer

Tags: flutter, 3d

the code is given below

```
// Dart Program to add 3D objects to your project

// importing material.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// importing flutter cube package
import 'package:flutter_cube/flutter_cube.dart';

// creating class of stateful widget
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
// adding necessary objects
  late Object floor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // assigning name to the objects and providing the
    // object's file path (obj file)
    floor = Object(fileName: "assets/floor/cartoon_wooden_floor_obj.obj");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,

        // creating appbar
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "3D Objects in Flutter",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 25),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Cube(
            onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
              scene.world.add(floor);
              scene.camera.zoom = 10;
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The file structure and 3D viewer results can be found

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81lWO.png)

The screenshot of the flutter app can be found
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2AiO.png)

texture is missing in this.

I'm trying to create virtual space using 3d cube pakage in flutter.
But the 3D models are missing textures and only black models are visible without color.
whereas in the windows 3D Viewer the texture is visible.